# Isomorphism between Hom modules

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

This question arose from one of my recent reading projects. Let $M$ and $N$ be $R$-modules and let
$$f:\hom(M,M)\to\hom(N,N)$$
be an $R$-module homomorphism such that $f(\textrm{id}_M)=\textrm{id}_N$. Can we conclude from this that $f$ is an isomorphism? Can we conclude that $f$ is an isomorphism if $M$ and $N$ are $k$-vector spaces or if $M$ and $N$ are finite-dimensional $k$-vector spaces. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You can’t conclude much of anything.

Let $R=k$ be a field. Then pick $n$ not dividing the characteristic and consider the map
$$
f\colon\mathrm{Mat}_{n\times n}(k)\to\mathrm{Mat}_{1 \times 1}(k)=k
$$
given by $f(A)=\frac{1}{n}\mathrm{trace}(A)$. Further, by using this map you can produce other maps into $\mathrm{Mat}_{m\times m}(k)$ with your desired property for any $m$, by scaling the identity matrix.

Another type of counterexample can be made by taking $R=M=\mathbb{Z}$, and $N=\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$.